# Performing a T-Test on a Multiindex Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scipy

I'm looking to perform a T-test on various pieces of data in a pandas DataFrame.

I have a dataframe organized like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {('0hr', '0.01um', 0): 12,
      ('0hr', '0.01um', 1): 10,
      ('0hr', '0.1um', 0): 8,
      ('0hr', '0.1um', 1): 6,
      ('0hr', 'Control', 0): 4,
      ('0hr', 'Control', 1): 2,
      ('24hr', '0.01um', 0): 18,
      ('24hr', '0.01um', 1): 15,
      ('24hr', '0.1um', 0): 12,
      ('24hr', '0.1um', 1): 9,
      ('24hr', 'Control', 0): 6,
      ('24hr', 'Control', 1): 3},
     'b': {('0hr', '0.01um', 0): 42,
      ('0hr', '0.01um', 1): 35,
      ('0hr', '0.1um', 0): 28,
      ('0hr', '0.1um', 1): 21,
      ('0hr', 'Control', 0): 14,
      ('0hr', 'Control', 1): 7,
      ('24hr', '0.01um', 0): 30,
      ('24hr', '0.01um', 1): 25,
      ('24hr', '0.1um', 0): 20,
      ('24hr', '0.1um', 1): 15,
      ('24hr', 'Control', 0): 10,
      ('24hr', 'Control', 1): 5}})
```

print(df)

```
                     a   b
    0hr  0.01um  0  12  42
                 1  10  35
         0.1um   0   8  28
                 1   6  21
         Control 0   4  14
                 1   2   7
    24hr 0.01um  0  18  30
                 1  15  25
         0.1um   0  12  20
                 1   9  15
         Control 0   6  10
                 1   3   5
```

For each column (a,b,etc.) I'd like to calculate perform a t-test comparing the Control for a given time frame to the other tests in that time frame.

For example :

```
[t, prob] = stats.ttest_ind( df.loc['0hr'].loc['Control'] , df.loc['0hr'].loc['Control'], 1, equal_var=True)
[t, prob] = stats.ttest_ind( df.loc['0hr'].loc['Control'] , df.loc['0hr'].loc['0.01um'], 1, equal_var=True)
[t, prob] = stats.ttest_ind( df.loc['0hr'].loc['Control'] , df.loc['0hr'].loc['0.1um'], 1, equal_var=True)
[t, prob] = stats.ttest_ind( df.loc['24hr'].loc['Control'] , df.loc['24hr'].loc['Control'], 1, equal_var=True)
[t, prob] = stats.ttest_ind( df.loc['24hr'].loc['Control'] , df.loc['24hr'].loc['0.01um'], 1, equal_var=True)
[t, prob] = stats.ttest_ind( df.loc['24hr'].loc['Control'] , df.loc['24hr'].loc['0.1um'], 1, equal_var=True)
```

I've been trying to do this with df.apply but I'm not sure what the right syntax is.  I'd like to return the results into a new dataframe structured like :

```
results = pd.DataFrame({'a': {('0hr', '0.01um', 't'): '-',
  ('0hr', '0.01um', 'prob'): '-',
  ('0hr', '0.1um', 't'): '-',
  ('0hr', '0.1um', 'prob'): '-',
  ('0hr', 'Control', 't'): '-',
  ('0hr', 'Control', 'prob'): '-',
  ('24hr', '0.01um', 't'): '-',
  ('24hr', '0.01um', 'prob'): '-',
  ('24hr', '0.1um', 't'): '-',
  ('24hr', '0.1um', 'prob'): '-',
  ('24hr', 'Control', 't'): '-',
  ('24hr', 'Control', 'prob'): '-'},
 'b': {('0hr', '0.01um', 't'): '-',
  ('0hr', '0.01um', 'prob'): '-',
  ('0hr', '0.1um', 't'): '-',
  ('0hr', '0.1um', 'prob'): '-',
  ('0hr', 'Control', 't'): '-',
  ('0hr', 'Control', 'prob'): '-',
  ('24hr', '0.01um', 't'): '-',
  ('24hr', '0.01um', 'prob'): '-',
  ('24hr', '0.1um', 't'): '-',
  ('24hr', '0.1um', 'prob'): '-',
  ('24hr', 'Control', 't'): '-',
  ('24hr', 'Control', 'prob'): '-'}})
```

Comment: Have you considered using anova test? It is exactly a t-test for several samples (easy to find e.g. in wikipedia). I've run it for the dataset you provide and the result is that at least one sample is different. Then you run tukey's HSD to know which one it is (one, or more than one). This I've also tried but honestly I was not able to treat properly your multiindex. It would give you in a nice list which samples are different and which ones are not. Do you really need the results in the format you propose in your question??

Comment: I'm open to the format of the results but I do believe I need a t-test. It's not my experimental data so I'm providing what was asked for ... a 2 tailed independent t-test.  I need to report the p-value.  This seemed to make sense to me as there are only two data sets being compared at any given time (e.g. 0.01um vs. Control or 0.1um vs. Control).  As far as I understand ANOVA is for comparing multiple data sets.

Comment: The point is that I don't think I've understood it, sorry. Ok, no ANOVA. But then, you will run 24x2 t-tests?? Maybe I still haven't understood... Anyway, if you want to apply a value to a multiindex, it would be something like `df.loc['0hr'].loc['0.01um']['t'] = xxx`, assuming that 't' is a column. For your dataframe, I've tried it straight in ipython as `df.loc['0hr'].loc['0.01um'].loc[0]['a'] = 3`. But if again I haven't understood, just tell me!

Comment: In the example above there would be 12 t-tests.  [t, prob] = stats.ttest_ind( df.loc['0hr'].loc['Control']['a'] , df.loc['0hr'].loc['Control']['a'], 1, equal_var=True) should yield p =1. The other tests would be  [t, prob] = stats.ttest_ind( df.loc['0hr'].loc['Control']['a'] , df.loc['0hr'].loc['0.01um']['a'], [t, prob] = stats.ttest_ind( df.loc['0hr'].loc['Control']['a'] , df.loc['0hr'].loc['0.1um']['a'], etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not completely sure that I've understood the situation, but I think this would be the way to handle the MultiIndex.

```
In [195]:

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([set(df.index.get_level_values(0)), set(df.index.get_level_values(1)), ['t', 'p']])
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'], index=index)

for time in set(df.index.get_level_values(0)):
    for condition in set(df.index.get_level_values(1)) - set(['Control']):
        t, p = stats.ttest_ind( df.loc[time].loc['Control'] , df.loc[time].loc[condition], 1, equal_var=True)
        result.loc[(time, condition, 't')] = t
        result.loc[(time, condition, 'p')] = p
print result
```

And the result:

```
                        a           b
0hr  Control t        NaN         NaN
             p        NaN         NaN
     0.01um  t -0.6706134   -1.412036
             p  0.5715365   0.2934382
     0.1um   t -0.8049845    -1.13842
             p  0.5053153   0.3729403
24hr Control t        NaN         NaN
             p        NaN         NaN
     0.01um  t  -2.529822   -3.137858
             p  0.1271284  0.08831539
     0.1um   t  -1.788854   -2.529822
             p  0.2155355   0.1271284
```

You could easily fill in the Control lines if you needed to, but as you say the results are predictable.

Hope it helps anyway.